# Classification with Least Angle (LARS)-type algorithm?

Tags: classification, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet, lars

I am currently working on the LARS (Least Angle Regression) method.

I know it is a regression method, but I wonder if, like LASSO or Ridge techniques (e.g. the package *gmlnet* in R), it can be modified in order to achieve classification rather than regression.

Comment: Well, LARS is an algorithm to fit Lasso models. Of course, [glmnet fits sparse logistic regressions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.html#log), although it doesn't use LARS (see section 3.2.2 in [Hastie, Tibshirani & Wainwright](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/). I'd assume that the nonlinearity in GLMs precludes using a least-angle approach. Why are you interested in specifically generalizing LARS?

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I am working on an implementation of LARS in a software and I was asked to look for possible improvements. Besides, I may need classification algorithms designed for high dimension very soon. So I thought to try to adapt LARS to classification if it is possible. If it's not, I'll try to implement another algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you would need to change is the inclusion of a link function to map the outcomes to the appropriate scale, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^k \to (0,1)^k$ and change the loss function to be a categorical loss such as multinomial log loss over $k$ categories.

These are essentially the only points of departure between regression problems with real-valued outcomes and outcomes which are restricted so some particular set.